# How do I autostart and use openvpn cli on Ubuntu 16.04 after suspend / resume?

Tags: suspend, openvpn

I was wondering, how do I make openvpn reconnect after I wake up my computer from system resume? I'm trying to use openvpn cli, not through the network manager with .ovpn files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that there is already an openvpn startup script that scans for .conf files (you can just change the extension from .ovpn to .conf). For restarting openvpn after waking up my computer, though, I was able to create a systemd service that works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Name the file openvpn-reconnect.service and put the following inside:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart OpenVPN after suspend
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart openvpn.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

I recommend first making sure that only your VPN's dns servers are used by default. Disable the bugged out and totally pointless dnsmasq local dns server thing ubuntu uses that mucks with dns resolution (see article here: [disabling-dnsmasq-as-your-local-dns-server-in-ubuntu](http://mark.orbum.net/2012/05/14/disabling-dnsmasq-as-your-local-dns-server-in-ubuntu/)) by commenting out (adding a #) to the beginning of the line dns=dnsmasq while editing the network manager config file like so:

```
sudo emacs /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Then, after saving the file, click on the GUI network manager applet, select "Edit Connections", select the primary (non-VPN) network you use, click on the "IPv6 Settings" tab, ignore IPv6 traffic by clicking on the "IPv6 Settings" tab and selecting Ignore" in the "Method" menu. Save your changes, then restart the network manager with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now to get ovpn working through the command line:

Create an auth.txt file containing:

```
<username>
<password>
```

For example, a sample auth.txt could contain two lines like so:

```
user1234
password1234
```

Edit .ovpn (or .conf) files to use auth.txt for automated login:
find line containing auth-user-pass and append auth.txt to the end like so:

```
...
auth-user-pass auth.txt
...
```

If your file contains the option auth-nocache, delete that line. auth-user-pass and auth-nocache are NOT compatible! The openvpn man pages explicitly say

```
Further,  using --daemon together with --auth-user-pass (entered
          on console) and --auth-nocache will fail as soon as key renego‐
          tiation (and reauthentication) occurs.
```

This jargon essentially means that openvpn will die spontaneously while you are browsing or streaming or whatever if you include the auth-nocache line in your config file.

Rename .ovpn files to .conf files:

```
mv <filename>.ovpn <filename>.conf
```

Place necessary .conf, .pem, and .crt files in a directory
Copy contents of directory to /etc/openvpn:

```
sudo cp <path-to-auth-crt-pem-and-conf-files>/* /etc/openvpn
```

Specify which connection should autostart when openvpn is started by
editing /etc/default/openvpn (the configuration file for /etc/init.d/openvpn)

```
sudo emacs /etc/default/openvpn
```

Add names of .conf files minus extension below #AUTOSTART="all"
for example, if I have two .conf files called US-East and US-East-Strong,

```
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="US-East"
#AUTOSTART="US-East-Strong"
```

Uncomment (remove # sign) from AUTOSTART directive of single connection
you want active. Every time you change which connection to autostart, run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl stop openvpn*
sudo systemctl start openvpn.service
```

To make openvpn reconnect after suspend, use openvpn-reconnect.service

Put service file where systemd can find it:

```
sudo cp openvpn-reconnect.service /lib/systemd/system
```

Enable and create symlinks using:

```
sudo systemctl enable openvpn-reconnect.service
```

To check status of openvpn connection, use:

```
systemctl status openvpn@<conf-filename-minus-extension>.service
```

for example, if my conf file is called US-East.conf:

```
systemctl status openvpn@US-East.service
```

if scrollable, type q to exit to shell.